# Delay when send string via socket

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I make an application in android can send character code to server C# when user input on android keyboard. 
This is send method in android side:

```
  public Boolean writeMessage(String message) {
    try {               
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.println(message);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG,"write error: " +ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And server listen the messages (C#):

```
     Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServeClient));
     myThread.Start();

     void ServeClient(){
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());     
          while (true)
          {
            try
            {
                String message = reader.ReadLine();
                if (message != null)
                {                     
                    Console.WriteLine(message);         
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

My code works, but when user input faster, the server delay read message in 1,2 or 3 seconds (I have test the method get character when user input, it works fine, not delay). 
Where is my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to multithread your server.

Comment: Of course, this code above is put in thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) reducing TCP traffic. Consider setting `TCP_NODELAY` on your client (**and** server - `TcpClient.Client.NoDelay` - if communication is two-way).

**Edit:** For java it is `Socket.setTcpNoDelay` method.